# How to use otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address?

Tags: openthread

I can’t find out how to use `otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address`. I am using two devices, one is the leader and the other is a child. I need the leader to get child addresses, is it possible to do it with this API?

I have tried with arguments below but it returned `OT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.

- `aChildIndex`: I have set it to `0`. I am quite sure the issue does not come from the index as I used `otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex` above with `0` index and it works fine.
- `aIterator`: I have created a `otChildIp6AddressIterator` variable and I have passed its address to the API.
- `aAddress`: I have created a `otIp6Address` variable and I have passed its address to the API.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the OpenThread CLI implementation for an [example of using `otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address()`](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/58419376bf3b9177f1883a1f402c15869e51e75d/src/cli/cli.cpp#L936).

Comment: I have already seen the CLI implementation of this function. I use it the same way as CLI does but for some reasons, according to the debugger, `OT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND` is returned in `Child::GetNextIp6Address` because mIp6Address seems to be unspecified. I can read correctly the addresses directly on the child device, so I can't figure why the leader keeps saying that the child addresses are unspecified.

Comment: Is your child a Full Thread Device (FTD)? Thread Routers do not maintain IPv6 addresses for children that are FTDs.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now, I can get correctly the Mesh Local one but the others seem not to be registered. How can I register all child’s addresses to get them all using `otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address` ? I guess the problem comes from my `AddressRegistrationMode` which seems to be set to `kAppendMeshLocalOnly`. Is there a way to set it to `kAppendAllAddresses` ?

Comment: Thread does not provide a mechanism for a Full Thread Device (FTD) operating in the child role to register its addresses with its Parent.

Comment: My child was FTD, that is why I was not able to get anything. But now, the child is MTD as you suggested. Its parent (FTD) needs to get the addresses (all of them) of this child. I tried using `otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address` but I only get the Mesh local address. What can I do to get all the child’s addresses ?

Comment: An MTD should register all non-link-local IPv6 addresses with its parent. Are you seeing non-link-local IPv6 addresses on the MTD that are not retrievable on the parent?

Comment: On child board : `otIp6GetUnicastAddresses` returns 3 addresses (Link-local, Mesh-local EID and RLOC).  On parent board : `otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address` returns only Mesh-local EID. If an MTD is supposed to register all non-link-local IPv6 addresses, then I should see the RLOC too right ?

Comment: Child devices do not need to register the RLOC because it is constructed from the Router ID and Child ID. Currently, `otThreadGetChildNextIp6Address()` only returns registered IPv6 addresses. You can obtain the RLOC16 by using `otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex()`.

Comment: It works using `otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex`, thank you.